# Is "껍질은 칼로 깎으시오." a wrong sentence? Should it be written "껍질은 칼으로 깎으시오."

Tags: grammar

When I read this sentence, I thought this might be wrong.

"껍질은 **칼로** 깎으시오."

Should it be written  "껍질은 **칼으로** 깎으시오." because "칼" has patim.

My text book is an old book , so it may be a kind of mistake, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"칼**로**" is right.

**When the preceding noun has the final consonant, ‘으로’ is used.**
by phone --> 폰으로(O) 폰로(X)
by book  --> 책으로(O) 책로(X)

**When the preceding noun does not have the final consonant, ‘로’ is used.**
★ But exceptionally, when the noun ends with 'ㄹ', '로' is used, not of '으로'.
by knife  --> 칼으로(X) 칼로(O)
by subway --> 지하철으로(X) 지하철로(O)
by pencil --> 연필으로(X) 연필로(O)

[reference(National Institute of the Korean Language)](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=128005)